# SQL: Create multiple columns from a single column

Tags: sql, oracle

The input data:
[image]

The query for the input data-

```
CREATE TABLE CustTable
(CustNum NUMBER(5), 
CntYear NUMBER(4),
TotalBill NUMBER(4));

INSERT INTO CustTable (CustNum, CntYear, TotalBill)
VALUES (101, 2013, 800);
INSERT INTO CustTable (CustNum, CntYear, TotalBill)
VALUES (101, 2015, 700);
INSERT INTO CustTable (CustNum, CntYear, TotalBill)
VALUES (102, 2013, 900);
INSERT INTO CustTable (CustNum, CntYear, TotalBill)
VALUES (102, 2015, 1000);
```

I want to get the following output-

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Pivot/self join. Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
select a.custnum, a.cntyear CurrContractYear, a.totalbill CurrBill, 
    b.cntyear NextContractYear, b.totalbill NextBill
from CustTable a inner join CustTable b
    on a.CustNum = b.CustNum
where b.CntYear > a.CntYear;
```

Comment: Thank you, was really quick.

Comment: Put a row in for `CustNum = 102` and `cntyear = 2016`.  I don't think you will get the results you are looking for.

Comment: But this is not according to the question he stated.

Comment: OK, thanks. Let's add another level over here. Say, there are two more records as 103, 2013, 2000 and 104, 2015, 3000. So, these two records should also show up in the output table. First one will have Next... as 0 and the second will have Curr... as 0

Answer (score 1):

This version should work for cases where there are more than 2 distinct contract years for a given customer.  It's also more efficient.

```
select * from (
select a.custnum, a.cntyear CurrContractYear, a.totalbill CurrBill, 
    lead(a.cntyear,1) over ( partition by a.custnum order by a.cntyear) NextContractYear, 
    lead(a.totalbill,1) over ( partition by a.custnum order by a.cntyear)  NextBill
from CustTable a
)
where nextcontractyear is not null
order by 1,2;
```

Comment: Thanks, it also works. I have added one more clause to it, in the above comment. You may give it a try.